# If a value in JSON is 'true' then register the 'id' value

Tags: python, json

The JSON template I'm working on looks like this:

[image]

My Code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

with open("Live.csv", "w+", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
    titlemenu = "id" + "\n"
    f.write(titlemenu)
    url = f'https://etcetcetc.com'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    events = response['events']
    for event in events:
        if 'true' in event['hasEventPlayerStatistics']:
            id = event['id']
            row = str(id) + "\n"
            f.write(row)
    f.close()
```

The message error is:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
```

How should I work this `if` to be able to retrieve these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here.

```
if 'true' in event['hasEventPlayerStatistics']:
```

`event['hasEventPlayerStatistics']` is already a python bool object. So you only need to do

```
if event['hasEventPlayerStatistics']:
      pass # do something
```

When you do [`.json` call on the response object](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) it already does the [following translations.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder)

| JSON | Python |
| --- | --- |
| true | True |
| false | False |

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it solved my problem, I'm just waiting for the deadline to be able to mark your answer as the solution!